# Is there more salmonella in organic eggs

Tags: public-health

This paper elaborates the rates of salmonella in organic and other chicken:

[Salmonella prevalence in free-range and certified organic chickens](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16300088)

A friend recently claimed that the same was true from eggs and then I was later pointed to this article:

[Buy Organic Eggs to Avoid Salmonella Poisoning? Maybe Not](http://health.usnews.com/health-news/diet-fitness/infectious-diseases/articles/2010/08/25/buy-organic-eggs-to-avoid-salmonella-poisoning-maybe-not)

Is it true that you are less likely to get salmonella from organic eggs?

Comment: "A friend told me" isn't a [notable claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/37236). However, I found 2 articles that you can use, one for one against: [USNews](http://health.usnews.com/health-news/diet-fitness/infectious-diseases/articles/2010/08/25/buy-organic-eggs-to-avoid-salmonella-poisoning-maybe-not) & [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-107201/Myths-facts-eggs-Part-Three.html).

Comment: They are a nutritionist or something

Comment: Che article is back, can we add citations so the question stands on its own?